# URL special char as GET method issue

Tags: url, get

Unfortunately htmlentities, urlencode, htmlspecialchars - nothing seems to work for me. I am trying to send the string "Music & Dance" in the URL as GET params, like this:

```
http://www.example.com?myvar=str.....
```

When I try to receive `myvar`, it always shows "Music". What this means is, the string gets cut off at the `&` char.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I even tried to convert the header as UTF-8. Even that is of no help.

Answer (score 1):

The result should be `?myvar=Music%20%26%20Dance`.

Check that you both url-encode the values, and html-encode the complete url. The later is needed to make valid html.

Example:

```
var value1 = "Music & Dance";
var value2 = "Awesomeness";
var qs = "?myvar=" + urlencode(value1) + "&level=" + urlencode(value2);
// Result: "?myvar=Music%20%26%20Dance&level=Awesomeness"

var href = htmlencode(qs);
// Result: "?myvar=Music%20%26%20Dance&amp;level=Awesomeness";

write("<a href=\"" + href + "\">my link!</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

[STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66) defines the `&` as [reserved character](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-2.2). It is typically used to delimit name-value pairs.

As your `&` is part of the value, you need to percent-encode it → `%26`. So your value should be `Music%20%26%20Dance` (`%20` for space).